# How to add a FileChooser and DropDown inside an Eclipse FormToolKit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to add a FileChooser and a DropDown inside a formToolKit of eclipse.
I did not find any create method with the mentioned components.

How to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the toolkit does't provide create* methods for the widget, you can always create the widget as usual, and then use toolkit.adapt() methods